Web based P2P Auto-Discover Instant Messaging
ShareDrop (Github) allows you to send files to other devices in the same local network (i.e. devices with the same public IP address) without any configuration.
Are there any similar systems that

must work in Web browser (without client installation)
must be able to auto discover peers in LAN
must have instant messaging feature (Sharedrop does not have this feature)
must not be self-hosted
nice if use WebRTC

Have tried to find through Google or ChatGPT, also in stackoverflow and superuser, but can't get the answer, thus posted here. Thanks.

Is the item #2 technically possible?

@A.L You may try https://www.sharedrop.io/

I'm sorry, I meant that I wondered if #2 is possible in the context of a web browser, which has limitations when accessing to the network, especially LAN.

Just found PairDrop (Github). Has all features like ShareDrop, and it also allows long press / right click to send message.
